# Kendo UI Grid filtering by javascript does not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI Grid view.

The data is

```
subNodesArray = "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "[15] OTU2-XP(59.79)(55.75) -B", "[16] GE-XPE(57.36)(*)-B*"]


var grids = $('#alarmsGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    for(var i=0; i<subNodesArray.length;i++){
        console.log(subNodesArray[i])
        grids.dataSource.filter({
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
                { field: "sourceId", operator: "eq", value: subNodesArray[i] },
            ]
        });
    }
```

Here filtering is not working for me.

Comment: You're overwriting the filter each iteration. You need to build the array then set it to the `dataSource.filter` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var subNodesArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "[15] OTU2-XP(59.79)(55.75) -B", "[16] GE-XPE(57.36)(*)-B*"];

var filters = [];
for(var i=0; i<subNodesArray.length;i++){
    filters.push({ field: "sourceId", operator: "eq", value: subNodesArray[i] });
}
$('#alarmsGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({
    "logic":"or",
    "filters":filters
});
```